# To extend the highlighted region to the sidebar second region

Tags: theming

my current account page looks like:
[image: Current scenario]

What I would like to do is to extend the highlighted region so it stretches to take the full width(highlighted + sidebar second), and having blocks in the sidebar second region appear below it, like so:

[image: goal]

Please suggest any ways I can achieve this.

Config: Drupal 7 with Bartik theme.

Thanks.

Comment: What theme are you using. Please update your question with that information.

Comment: You need to change on css.

Comment: @Smalution can you please explain how ?

Comment: increase the width of highlighted region and you may need to use clear:both. But i wants to tell you that it is not good to edit core theme. There are so many contributed theme available you can choose one according to your requirement and edit.